# If you introduce a friend within a class in the global namespace, the friend is injected globally

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend-function

You can inject a friend declaration into a namespace by declaring it within an enclosed class:

```
namespace Me {
class Us {
friend void you();
};
}
```

Now the function you( ) is a member of the namespace Me.
If you introduce a friend within a class in the global namespace, the
friend is injected globally.

Can someone explain with an example what is meaning of above lines.

Comment: You should explain what it is you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a friend declaration into a namespace by declaring it within an enclosed class:

```
namespace Me {
class Us {
friend void you();
};
}
```

Now the function you( ) is a member of the namespace Me.
If you introduce a friend within a class in the global namespace, the
friend is injected globally.